# Move multiple files from folder A to folder B

Tags: powershell, server, directory

We need to move .csv files from folder where the are stored down to external server using powershell.

this is what i've tried so far but for some reason i only get message not copying and name of the files:

```
$DestinationFolder = "C:\d1\"
$SourceFolder = "C:\s1\"
If (-not (Test-Path $DestinationFolder) ) {
  New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $DestinationFolder
}
$EarliestModifiedTime = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(200).Date     # get's current time + adds 30 min
$LatestModifiedTime = (Get-Date).Date   
echo($DestinationFolder);                # will check time 
Get-ChildItem "C:\s1\*.*"  |
ForEach-Object {
if ( ($_.CreationTime -ge $EarliestModifiedTime) -and ($_.CreationTime -lt $LatestModifiedTime) ){   # i.e., all day yesterday
Copy-Item $_ -Destination $DestinationFolder -Force 
Write-Host "Copied $_" }
else {
Write-Host "Not copying $_"
}
}
```

Comment: You say you want to move .csv files, but your code uses `*.*` meaning **all filetypes**. Also the code doesn't move, but instead copy files.. Then, you set `$EarliestModifiedTime` to 200 minutes in the future, so `$_.CreationTime -ge $EarliestModifiedTime` will always fail and last but not least, you're not looking at the Mdified date (which would be `LastWriteTime`, but use `CreationTime` instead. The latter is changable if you copy or move a ile to a different location..

Comment: So, what exactly is your question? Move .csv files older than 30 minutes ?

Comment: Okay my question is how do i modify the code so lets just simplify it to .csv will be copied over to another folder every 30 min interval created on the same day

Answer (score 0):

does it work if you simplify it and just try for a test (e.g. pick one file rather than trying to run for a delta of every 30 mins / last day)? Just thinking first you need to see if the problem is with accessing (or the formatting) of your source / destination directories or the delta logic itself. Perhaps some more error conditions would help....

Comment: so its actually has to be from same day. im not very good on powershell.

Comment: the connection works location of the files are correct however time condition is not right & perhaps copy function is also incorect